# Center a block of lines in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={4.8 in, 6.4 in}, top=0.10cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=0.2cm, left=0.2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\enspace}                                                                       \\
left-aligned text in column 1                & left-aligned text in column 2                       \\
left-aligned text in column 1                & left-aligned text in column 2                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\enspace}                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\hspace{20pt} short line (left-aligned centered block)}                         \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\hspace{20pt} now a longer (line in the same left-aligned centered block)}      \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\enspace}                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{short line (centered, not left-aligned)}                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{this is a longer line (centered, not left-aligned)}                             \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\enspace}                                                                       \\
left-aligned text in column 1                & left-aligned text in column 2                       \\
left-aligned text in column 1                & left-aligned text in column 2                       \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I have a two-column table and I need to center text that spans the two columns while staying left-aligned.

In the above code I use a left-aligned multicolumn and \hspace to arbitrarily indent the block by 20pt.

Is there any way I can have the compiler compute the width/length of the indentation?

A suitable indentation for the block to be centered should be something like: (width of the table - average line length) / 2.

What would be the proper way to do this?

**Update:**

I went for the nested tabular and got pretty much the same layout as the original:

[image]

Comment: If you have several such \multicolumns,  do they have to be left-aligned w.r.t. each other?

Comment: use NiceTabular with the option block

Comment: @Bernard in the original document the French printer typesetter didn't do it. My last shot is pretty close to what he came up with. I ususally try to do this outside table when, e.g. the text is interspersed with bits of verse or songs… provided the lines are the same length in case two such end up on the same page. I feel it looks better when they are aligned with regards to each other.

Comment: @jsbibra would that be package nicematrix? I don't need yet another package at this point but after a cursorily look at the documentation it looks like it may come in handy if I need to do something more complex at some point.

Comment: You can obtain his result automatically with`the `eqparbox` package: among others, the `\eqparbox{tag}{…}` command makes all eqparboxes sharing the same tag have the width of the largest natural width of each content. See the documentation, for more details.

Comment: Before I let go of this… I noticed that in the above rendition there is no vertical line between between 'Potage sagou lié.' and 'Consommé en tasses.' (line 3 or thereabout). This is apparaently due to my having multicolumned{1}{c}{...} so as to center these two items. No big deal but is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

With  `stackengine`, and its `\Centerstack` command, which can take an optional argument for the alignment (default is `c`), and `\addlinespace`(from `booktabs`) to simplify the vertical spacing around these blocks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={4.8 in, 6.4 in}, top=0.10cm, bottom=0.5cm, hmargin=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\scriptsize\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{2.7ex}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\enspace} \\
left-aligned text in column 1 & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
left-aligned text in column 1 & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\Centerstack[l]{short line (left-aligned centered block) \\
now a longer (line in the same left-aligned centered block)}} \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\Centerstack{short line (centered, not left-aligned) \\
this is a longer line (centered, not left-aligned)}} \\
\addlinespace
left-aligned text in column 1 & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
left-aligned text in column 1 & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:  loading `eqparbox`, you can obtain this alignment withe the code below:

```
\begin{center}
\scriptsize\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{2.7ex}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\enspace} \\
left-aligned text in column 1 & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
left-aligned text in column 1 & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\eqparbox{LC}{\Centerstack[l]{short line (left-aligned centered block) \\
now a longer (line in the same left-aligned centered block)}}} \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\eqparbox{LC}{\Centerstack[l]{short line (centered, not left-aligned) \\
this is a longer line (centered, not left-aligned)}}} \\
\addlinespace
left-aligned text in column 1 & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
left-aligned text in column 1 & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. You can delete your previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

With the following two little tricks you can get two lines that are left aligned with respect to each other, but centered within the table.

In the first example, I have used a single, centered `p` type column for both lines of text, while the second example is based on a nested left aligned tabular inside of a centered multicolumn.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[papersize={4.8 in, 6.4 in}, top=0.10cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=0.2cm, left=0.2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\enspace}                                                                             \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2                                          \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2                                          \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}                                                                                     \\
\multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8cm}}{short line (centered, not left-aligned) 
                                                    \newline 
                                                    this is a longer line (centered, not left-aligned)}  \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}                                                                                     \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2                                          \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2                                          \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}                                                                                     \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} 
                     short line (centered, not left-aligned) \\ 
                     this is a longer line (centered, not left-aligned)
                   \end{tabular}}                                                                        \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}                                                                                     \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2                                          \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2                                          \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

By using `\makecell` and `\mbox` your table can be written also on the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={4.8 in, 6.4 in}, 
            top=0.10cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=0.2cm, left=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{2}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\mcc{}                                                          \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
\mcc{}                                                          \\
\mcc{\mbox{%
     \makecell[l]{short line (centered, not left-aligned)\\
                  this is a longer line 
                  (centered, not left-aligned)}}
     }                                                          \\
\mcc{}                                                          \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
\mcc{}                                                          \\
\mcc{short line (centered, not left-aligned)}                   \\
\mcc{this is a longer line (centered, not left-aligned)}        \\
\mcc{}                                                          \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
left-aligned text in column 1   & left-aligned text in column 2 \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]